# Setting selected values in selectManyChoice

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I have an af:table with a selectManyChoice as a filter in one of the columns. It looks like this

```
<af:column sortProperty="#{bindings.my_list_view.hints.statusId.name}"
           filterable="true" sortable="true" headerText="Status"
           id="column_status">
    <f:facet name="filter">
    <af:selectManyChoice id="smc_status"
                         value="#{vs.filterCriteria.statusId}"
                         valuePassThru="false" autoSubmit="true"
                         contentStyle="width:100px"
                         binding="#{wrapper.filter_status}">
        <af:forEach var="listrow" items="#{ViewData.status_List}">
            <f:selectItem id="si_status_1" itemValue="#{listrow.value}"
                          itemLabel="#{listrow.label}"/>
        </af:forEach>
    </af:selectManyChoice>
</f:facet>
<af:outputText value="#{row.status}" id="output_status"/>
```

I want to preselect some of the values in the selectManyChoice, but how can I preselect values in this dropdown?

I am using JDev 11.1.2.3.0

Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a binding of your RichSelectManyChoice in your bean and then create a function which will set the default values. To set the default values you need to create a list, add what you want and then set the value in the maychoice.

```
ArrayList listVal = new ArrayList(20);
listVal.add(101);
listVal.add(102);
// Set List as value
selectMcBind.setValue(listVal.toArray());
//Refresh Component on page (partial target)
AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(selectMcBind);
```